# how to put array as an argument in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have tried using array as parameter but when trying to put an array as an argument I get following error:

> required: int,int[]
>     found: int,int
>     reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to int[] by method invocation conversion
>   2 errors

*Source Code:*

```
public class utopian{

    void height(int t,int[] n){

    n = new int[100];
    for (int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int k = n[i];
        if (k%2==0){
            for(int j=0;j<=k;j=j+2){
                int h=1;
                h=h*2;
                h=h+1;

            }}
            else{
                for(int j=0;j<=k;j=j+2){
                int h=1;
                h=h*2;
                h=h+1;

            }
           int h=h*2;    
            }
    System.out.println(h);  
            }        
    }

}
```

--

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        utopian heht = new utopian();
        heht.height(2,{0,1})
}}
```

I want to use array as an argument and I cannot understand how.

Comment: You have to initialize the new array first then pass it in.

Comment: Use `new int[] {0, 1}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
utopian heht = new utopian();
int array[]={0,1};//Declaration of array
heht.height(2,array)//pass array
```

Other than that inline declaration won't allow you to reuse the array.

```
heht.height(2, new int[] {0,1});//Here you can't reuse the array in further code
//if you don't want to reuse it than go for this
```

Answer (score 2):

```
heht.height(2, new int[] {0,1})
```

However there are places for a less verbose notation, which probably misled you:

```
int[] data = {0, 1};
```